# Get value via class in AJAX form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to submit a HTML from using AJAX.

My HTML:

```
<form class="lyrics">
     <input type="text" value="" id="song" name="song">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info lirik">lyrics</button>
</form>
```

I have dynamic form. so it can more than 1 form.
My Javascript:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".lyrics").bind("submit", function() {
        var value = $("#song").val();
        alert(value);
        $.post("lihat_lirik.php", {
            value: value
        }, function(data) {
             $("#lyric_results").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

How can I get the song value from the form input as var?

Here [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/eumtn300/)
Its work in first form but not on the second one,

Comment: alert(value); works, so what is your php doing?

Comment: @ Suhindra where do you want to get `song value`

Comment: Have you included jQuery ? I have checked in JSFiddle and it works

Comment: @ozil can i got song from input value as var in javascript?

Comment: @SheldonNeilson alert(value); doesn't work "undefined"

Comment: You already have the value of the "song" input box in JS: var value = $("#song").val();

Comment: What is your jquery version?

Comment: @SheldonNeilson but its "undefined" on alert();

Comment: Please show us the rest of your page. Your problem isn't in this piece of code. Are you sure you've included a reference to jQuery?

Comment: @SheldonNeilson i copy on js fidle same as my problem, it work on first form but not on second one. http://jsfiddle.net/eumtn300

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be valid. I would change `.bind()` by `.on()`:

```
$(function() {
    $(".lyrics").on("submit",function() {
        var value = $("#song").val();  
        alert(value);
        $.post("lihat_lirik.php",{value:value}, function(data){
            $("#lyric_results").html(data);
        });
       return false;
    });
});
```

The alert should show the value correctly.
So, check if jQuery is successfully loaded **and the html is already on the view when you try to get its inputs values**.

**Edit:**
You have 2 forms instead of one. It changes the things. And you have *more than one ID with value "song"*; an id should be an unique identifier.

Just replace `var value = $("#song").val();` by `var value = $("#song", this).val();`

[Check your updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/eumtn300/1/)

Comment: I think you have in your code or html views something that is no posted in your question. The code that you show us works fine. When we try the code at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/7x9wobo0/) it works as expected.

Comment: You are welcome. Anyway, for the next time I recommend you to post as much code as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your form is a delegated element ? (added by javascript, for example in ajax action). If that's true u should use this code:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '.lyrics', function() {
        var value = $("#song").val();
        alert(value);
        $.post("lihat_lirik.php", {
            value: value
        }, function(data) {
             $("#lyric_results").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

If not try the code from kmsdev with "on" instead of "bind". It should work properly. Of course if your jQuery library is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle you supplied [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eumtn300) you have two inputs with the same id, "song".

You would need to give your inputs unique id's in order to access their unique values like that.

Alternatively you can change your query to only include the child elements of the form that is currently being submitted like this:

```
<form class="lyrics">
     <input type="text" value="5" name="song">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info lirik">lyrics</button>
</form>
<form class="lyrics">
     <input type="text" value="6" name="song">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info lirik">lyrics</button>
</form>

$(function() {
    $(".lyrics").bind("submit", function(event) {
        var value = $(event.target).children("#song").val();
        alert(value);
        $.post("lihat_lirik.php", {
            value: value
        }, function(data) {
             $("#lyric_results").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```